# getting data from dynamically added form in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mean

I'm developing an app using MEAN stack. I'm able to add form elements dynamically but cannot get inserted data in my ng-model. if i put `ng-model="something.something"` then every dynamically added form elements takes same data. I wish to take data as in form of object inside a array.I would really appreciate any response.

Here is my html code:

```
  <div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-repeat="(key,aca) in vm.academic">
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Degree</label>
                    <input name="degree" ng-model="vm.academic[key].degree">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>University/Board</label>
                    <input name="university" ng-model="vm.academic[key].university">
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                    <label>Percentage/Grade</label>
                    <input name="grade" ng-model="vm.academic[key].grade">
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
            <div layout="row" layout-align-gt-sm="end">
                <md-button class="btn1" aria-label="add button" ng-click="vm.add();">
                    <md-icon md-svg-icon="plus"></md-icon>
                    <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                       Add more field
                    </md-tooltip>
                </md-button>
            </div>
```

and my js code is

```
   vm.academic = [{}];
   vm.add = add;

    function add() {
    console.log('button clicked');
    vm.academic.push({
        degree:'',
        university:'',
        grade:''
    });
};
```

How do I get a different ng-model for different fields to save the data in database?

Comment: Please find [here demo](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/RkykR/) to have detail about how to iterate over arrray and bind value into form using ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the html code that would help you format you html

```
 <form name="FormName" novalidate>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-repeat="aca in vm.academic">
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="aca.name" >
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="">
                <label for="email">Email Id</label>
                <input type="email" ng-model="aca.email"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And in you controller initialize `vm.academic = [{}];`
And call add and remove methods as follows

```
vm.addNewAcademic = function(){
   vm.academic.push({});
};
vm.removeAcademic = function() {
   var num = vm.academic.length-1;
   if ( num !== 0 ) {
      vm.academic.pop();
   }
};
```

You'll get in output result as `[{'name':'a','email':'bb'},{'name':'c','email':'dd'}]`

Comment: hello brother it again troubles me sending data to the server. how can i send ng-model data. i have long form which have ng-model="vm.recruit.formElement". how to send data along with vm.recruit

Comment: vm.recruit must be a dictionary object send this to server directly. What's difficulty in it?

Comment: well i am able to send data to node server. but i am using mongoose and mongodb for data storage. i am not able to save form-elements into array of schema. here is my server code:

Comment: i will post another question for this my code occupies more characters than it is allocated.